# how do I make unfocusing keyboard to edittext when App launchs?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have edittext on my Xml layout. When the app launch, keyboard is coming and focusing to edittext. I dont want this. How can I unfocus it on Android Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set **below** property of your parent/Top level layout.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and Its working Nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this line in your activity it will hide your soft input

`keyboardthis.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

Alternatively, you can use

```
edittext.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this following line with your activity tag  in manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

or

you can set following line in  oncreate method of your activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```